# Login and register on ASP.NET MVC 5/6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, registration

I'm beginning with asp.net mvc and I'd like to learn to the best way for user registration and login whitch is used in real projects. Please, can anyone share good tutorial for beginner? Thanks

Comment: do you use google to find some tutorial first ? eg: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of tutorials if you google "ASP.NET Identity 2.X".  Here is one I found [ASP.NET Identity Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics)

This should give you a foundation to build on if you need to do something more complex.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Membership api for user creation and login, And it is widely used in real projects.

check this link:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx